# Can't add files to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

So I can't seem to add any new files or groups to my projects and I'm not sure why...

This just started happening today, I try to right-click on my root folder and hit `New Group` but nothing shows up in Xcode. If I look in finder, I can see that it did make a folder called `New Group` but it didn't include it in the project and it won't show up in Xcode.

I also tried right-clicking on the root folder and hitting `Add files to ...` and then select the folder that was created in finder but nothing happens.

I've tried restarting Xcode, restarting my computer and clearing derived data, none of which did anything.

Has anyone experienced this before / knows how to fix it?

---

EDIT 1: Alright so after some digging in my .xcodeproj file, it looks like it actually *DID* add the new files to the project as I can see them declared in there, however they do not appear anywhere in Xcode and I can't navigate to them in the Xcode file browser.

The entire project is only 6 swift files (not including the new files), and only 5/6 files appear in the file browser on the right side of Xcode, and none of the new files appear.

---

EDIT 2: So I started thinking, maybe something just got messed up in my .xcodeproj file that's causing all of this, so ill try recloning my repo and opening it from a different location. I do this, and now Xcode only shows 1/6 files!!!

It can't find any of my project files except one, and I cloned a repo from an old commit that I know for sure is stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't think this is a good solution, but I uninstalled and re-installed Xcode and everything started working again... Who knows what the problem was, I guess now I never will know